# returned a non-zero code: 2 on EVERY SINGLE COMMAND in known good Dockerfiles

Tags: docker

I get a "returned a non-zero code: 2" on EVERY SINGLE COMMAND in known good Dockerfile

Even a simple RUN apt-get update throws the error.

The command '/bin/sh -c apt-get update' returned a non-zero code: 2

Can not RUN any commands at all. Is my Docker installation broken?

Comment: Post your Dockerfile

Comment: Also post your build command and the output.

Comment: Ok will attach it right after this meeting... it's just a simple PHP Sample Dockerfile that I have run before on another machine with no issues

Comment: Weird. I can only imagine a broken base image (for example rm /bin/sh...). Can you try some different base image?

Comment: FROM ubuntu:12.04

# Install dependencies
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y git curl apache2 php5 libapache2-mod-php5 php5-mcrypt php5-mysql

# Install app
RUN rm -rf /var/www/*
ADD src /var/www

# Configure apache
RUN a2enmod rewrite
RUN chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www
ENV APACHE_RUN_USER www-data
ENV APACHE_RUN_GROUP www-data
ENV APACHE_LOG_DIR /var/log/apache2

EXPOSE 80

CMD ["/usr/sbin/apache2", "-D",  "FOREGROUND"]

Comment: sudo docker build -t image1 .

Comment: This has all worked in the past... not sure what gives now

Comment: I can't even do a "docker run hello-world"  Lol... she broke!  I will move to another machine... removing and reinstalling does not fix it either.

Comment: Is the Docker engine running/installed with sudo permissions? I mean not the docker build command (sudo docker build), but the Docker engine binaries.

Comment: Yes that is correct..  It all works fine on my Mac... same Dockerfile.  On Ubuntu I get this... $ sudo docker run hello-world
panic: standard_init_linux.go:178: exec user process caused "exec format error" [recovered]
 panic: standard_init_linux.go:178: exec user process caused "exec format error"

goroutine 1 [running, locked to thread]:
panic(0x835c220, 0x975702c0)

Comment: Sorry guys turns out it was a 32 bit PC!

Comment: Go ahead and add that as an answer here, in case someone else runs into it. :)

Answer (score 0):

### Problem:

I had the dreaded error code `non-zero code: 2, Code: 2`.

When I executed `docker-compose build --no-cache` the specific error puked was:

```
Step 2/11 : RUN apk update
 ---> Running in c1133f64073e
fetch https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.16/main/aarch64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
ERROR: https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.16/main: temporary error (try again later)
WARNING: Ignoring https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.16/main: No such file or directory
fetch https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.16/community/aarch64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
ERROR: https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.16/community: temporary error (try again later)
WARNING: Ignoring https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.16/community: No such file or directory
2 errors; 42 distinct packages available
1 error occurred:
    * Status: The command '/bin/sh -c apk update' returned a non-zero code: 2, Code: 2
```

Appeared to be DNS related, but this was a red-herring.

Luckily I had (2) hosts that I could do comparative analysis with...

### Troubleshooting:

The same Dockerfile in my docker-compose config worked on one host, but not another. So syntax error could immediately be excluded as causal.

It appeared DNS related, but reviewing `/etc/default/docker' evidenced parity in the configs between the working & broken host and I could ping the DNS servers specified in that file.

I checked the Firewall and both hosts had all the same holes poked in it.

### Solution:

Docker was flaking:

```
sudo systemctl restart docker.service
```

When I now executed

```
docker-compose build --no-cache
```

Everything just worked.